# How to graph continuous independent variable and logit of dichotomous outcome in SPSS

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, logit, linearity

First question: I am using SPSS, and I want to graph the logit of my dependent variable on the y axis and my continuous independent variable on the x-axis.  I am interested in visualizing the relationship to see if it is linear and meets the assumption for binary logistic regression.

Second question: Based on a Box-Tidwell test, the variable meets the linearity assumption. If anyone knows an alternative to Box-Tidwell that the majority of statisticians agree is the current standard, please let me know.  If Box-Tidwell will suffice, that would be good to know as well. References are beneficial. Thank you.

Comment: Of interest, [Jittered scatterplots with 0-1 data](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/jittered-scatterplots-with-0-1-data/).